# Add mmDDyyyy to filename

Tags: powershell

How can I append "_05262015" to the end of a filename in powershell?  For example, I am opening the file, writing data to it, then saving.

```
#Opening
$extractFile = @"
\\C:\Test\book1.csv
"@
#Saving
$DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv $extractFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Have you looked at `Rename-Item` and `Get-Date`? Perhaps you want  string manipulation with `$extractFile`?

Comment: The part you commented `#Opening` doesn't open the file. It merely defines a variable with a filename (as a multiline string). Where does the filename come from? Do you have it in your code (so you can simply define the string differently), or does it come from somewhere else (so you have to modify the existing string)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manipulate an existing filename string you can do that (for instance) with methods of the [`IO.Path`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

```psh
$extractFile = 'C:\Test\book1.csv'

$date = Get-Date -f 'MMddyyyy'
$dirname  = [IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($extractFile)
$filename = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($extractFile) +
            "_$date" + [IO.Path]::GetExtension($extractFile)

$extractFile = Join-Path $dirname $filename
```

Comment: This saves in my current directory (where the ps1 script is) not in the destination designated in $extractFile

Answer (score 3):

Here is the way that I do it:

```
$extractFile = '\\C:\Test\book1_{0}.csv' -F (Get-Date).ToString('MMddyyyy')
```

Comment: can I keep the original filename in place and do something like: $savefilename = $extractFile  -Format (Get-Date).ToString('MMddyyyy')

Comment: @MasterOfStupidQuestions No.

Comment: This is not appending the date to the end of the filename?

Comment: @MasterOfStupidQuestions No. And even if it did, you don't want a filename `book1.csv_05262015`. Trust me.

Answer (score 2):

```
$extractFile = '\\C:\Test\book1.csv'
$suffix = Get-Date -Format '_MMddyyyy'
$newFile = $extractFile -replace '\.([^.]*)$',"$suffix.`$1"
Move-Item $extractFile -Destination $newFile
```

The [`-replace`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) operator does a [regular expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847880.aspx) replacement, and works like this:

First argument is the match pattern that we want to replace:

```
'\.([^.]*)$'
  ^   ^   ^
  |   |   |
 Dot  |   |
      |  End of string
     Capture group with 0 or more non-Dot characters (file extension)
```

Second argument is the string we want to replace the matched pattern with:

```
"$suffix.`$1"
    ^      ^
    |      |
    |     $1 refers to that first capture group from the match pattern, escaped to avoid string expansion
   PowerShell parser expands this to "__05262015" because we use double-quotes
```

So value of `$newFile` becomes `\\C:\Test\book1_05262015.csv` (at least today)

At last we use `Move-Item` with the full new path to effectively rename the file

Answer (score -1):

```
$newFileName = $extractFile + "_05262015"
$DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv $newFileName -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: while this technically does answer the question as it was literally asked. I feel that the OP really wanted the addition before the extension.

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted. Courtesy ping @humble.rumble who presumably was not the flagger.)

Comment: I down voted it because I don't feel it actually resolves the issue that the OP is having. I thought that my first comment made that clear.